# Panels in-place editor won't show in panels even after setting renderer

Tags: panels

My relevant specs are: Drupal 7, Jquery update 2.5.7 (set to 1.7), Ctools 1.7.7, and Panels 3.5.7.

**The problem:**

I've enabled "Panels in-place editor" to ease panels editing. I've set the renderer at Paenls>Settings` from "Standart" to "Panels in-place editor" and cleared cache - and yet, when standing at the Panel node I don't see it. reasons?

**notes:**

- The site has only 1 user, me, the Admin so it's not a permissions
  issue (also checked permissions).
- My layout was taken from "Panels extra layouts" module, if it makes
  any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

It seems to me that there are two types of renderes for panels:

The first is the **global** renderer that indeed I've changed to "Panels in-place editor". The second is each Panel's **own** or **Specific** renderer.

My problem occurred because for some reason, My Panel's **own** renderer wasn't affected from the global one, and stayed "Standart". I have no idea why that happen (might be a bug)...

Anyways, to change your Panel's own renderer just go to it's Panel.page\Panel.node and click on the tab "Edit" located on it's top. Thus when you edit the Panel itself you could choose it's own renderer and Problem should be solved by then.

All luck, Ben.

[image]